# How to reply to an email in a same conversation using gmail api in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, google-api, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail.users.messages.send function to send a reply to the same conversation using threadId but it doesn't work

```
gmail.users.messages.send({
      auth: auth,
      userId: 'me',
      resource: {
    raw: raw,
    threadId:threadId
    },
    });
```

Comment: Define `it doesn't work`

Comment: mails are being sent but a new thread is created for each mail

Comment: How are you retrieving `threadId`?

Comment: using the mail fetch API. Also, I've got the solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add "In-Reply-To" and "reference" into the raw object and to keep the subject the same as of the mail you're replying to.

```
const raw = {
 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
  "References: <n4Frx80qe2_bE5H5bQhgcqGk=GwFN9gs7Z_8oZw@mail.gmail.com> <CDLLRQuSHMCXLOra1NW70jvoNgR+hU59BYg@mail.gmail.com>\n" +
  "In-Reply-To: <CADsZLRwQWzLB-uq4_4G2E64NX9G6grn0cEeO0L=avY7ajzuAFg@mail.gmail.com>\n" +
  "Subject: Re: your subject\n" +
  "From: sender@gmail.com\n" +
  "To: reciever@gmail.com\n\n" +
}


gmail.users.messages.send({
      auth: auth,
      userId: 'me',
      resource: {
    raw: raw,
    },
    });
```

Comment: hello, what value we should pass at References and In-Reply-To?